# three.js - how to reproduce this image for 3d view?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a `tower image' - but i don't know how to reproduce this for`3d`view using the`three.js` any one help me?

here is the image :

[image]

here is my try :

```
$(function () {

    "use strict";

    var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
    var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

// custom global variables
var cube;

// initialization
init();

// animation loop / game loop
animate();



function init() 
{

    scene = new THREE.Scene();


    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;   

    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);

    scene.add(camera);

    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );

    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);

    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );




    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,0);
    scene.add(light);
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);


    var cloneTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/tower.png' );

    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, 1, 100, 32 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: cloneTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
    var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cylinder );

    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
    scene.add( axes );



    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/plain-grass-lawn.jpeg' );
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000, 1, 1);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(floor);

}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
}


function render() 
{   
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

});
```

here is my bad output :

[image: my output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to effectively display the image as a sprite in the 3D world? Like the Sprite example linked to below?

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/#sprites

Example source code for sprite rendering

https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples.source/webgl_sprites.html.html

Link to official three.js documentation in relation to sprites

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Sprite

Comment: I am very new to this technology. I don't know in which approach I need to select to reproduce this image. can you give further clue is this?

Comment: I've edited my original answer to link to some example code for sprite rendering. I've not actually used three.js at all, but am aware of the practice of sprite rendering for another 3d engine I've used in the past.

Comment: How to `lock` the bottom view? http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Animate.html - in this example you can view the bottom view. (below the check boxes ) but i would like to suspend that view.. how to do that?

Comment: As stated I have not used threejs myself. What you are asking is a completely separate issue, so I suggest you search for it / create a new question so that others who are better suited to helping will have a chance of seeing it. Good luck!